# Creating Multiple Objects in Ruby and then Comparing Them

Tags: ruby, class, object

My goal is to be able to assign each tea their own ID, compare prices and weights between teas, and do it all within the command line. What's a smart way to do this? Here is my code so far:

```
class Tea

    def initialize(name, price, shipping, weight)
       @name = name
       @price = price
       @shipping = shipping
       @weight = weight
       get_tea_details
       @total_price = total_price
    end

   def get_tea_details
       puts "Enter name: "
       @name = gets.chomp
       puts "Enter price: "
       @price = gets.chomp.to_f
       puts "Enter shipping cost: "
       @shipping = gets.chomp.to_f
       puts "Enter weight: "
       @weight = gets.chomp.to_i
   end

   def total_price
       @total_price = @price + @shipping
   end

   def price_difference
      price_difference = t1.total_price - t2.total_price
      print "#{price_difference}"
   end

end

puts "Do you want to compare teas?: "
answer = gets.chomp
if answer == "yes"
t1 = Tea.new(@name, @price, @shipping, @weight)
t1 = Tea.new(@name, @price, @shipping, @weight)
end

price_difference
```

Comment: I'm receiving this error: 

NameError: undefined local variable or method `price_difference' for main:Object

Comment: You've got a lot of problems in there... that error is because you're trying to access a method of the Tea class without a Tea object. You'd have to do t1.price_difference.

Your price difference function is also not going to work. Pay attention to my example. You need to take a second Tea object as an argument. You don't want to include a local variable in that method that has the same name as the method (price_difference).

I'll add into my example what that function should look like. You should really read up on Ruby Programming though. Run through a tutorial.

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work with t1.price_difference(t2). I'll keep running through tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but my guess is you want to know how to write a function to compare your Tea objects. You can do something like this:

```
class Tea
    attr_accessor :name, :price

    def price_difference(other)
            print (@price - other.price).abs
    end

    def compare(other)
        same = true

        if(@name != other.name)
            puts "They have different names."
            same = false
        end

        if(@price != other.price)
            puts "They have different prices."
            same = false
        end

        if same
            puts "They are exactly the same!"
        end
    end
end

t1 = Tea.new
t2 = Tea.new

t1.compare t2 
"They are exactly the same!"
```

I'd also recommend dropping the "tea_" prefix from your variables. It's unnecessary and adds a little readability.

Comment: Thank you! How would I calculate the difference in the total price between t1 and t2?